# Accessing the same view controller in a Storyboard by a subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uistoryboard

Hullo,
I would like to create a new target for a project without overcrowding the main view controller with #ifdef's. So I am thinking of splitting its functions with a weaker superclass and have the new target use the top one. How do I configure the new target to attach the top view controller to the view controller in the storyboard instead of the bottom one as in the old target?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to invoke and set the view controller manually like so:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UIViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifier"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Actually I instantiate my view controller with:
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        detailViewController=(inArrivoHDDetailViewController*)navController.topViewController; where should your piece of code conditionally enter? Also I have two different pieces of code for the iPhone and iPad - of which I am not particularly proud; I expected I could do something in the storyboard itself instead.